# Animation: Spin svg path on its own center inside a larger rect box

Tags: css, svg

How can I rotate(spin) a smaller svg path inside a larger rect on its own center.

This code rotate on entire space.

```
<animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                    attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="0 10 5"
                    to="360 10 5"
                    dur="1s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8vwk3jsj/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second and third values in the rotate transform are the X and Y coordinates of the centre of rotation.

Your problem was that you are using (10, 5), which is nowhere near the centre of your gear.  The correct value is (97.5, 177.5).

Updated snippet below:

```css
*{
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 161 231"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><rect class="cls-1" x="3.5" y="3.5" width="154" height="224" rx="8.5" ry="8.5"/>
<path d="M149,7a5,5,0,0,1,5,5V219a5,5,0,0,1-5,5H12a5,5,0,0,1-5-5V12a5,5,0,0,1,5-5H149m0-7H12A12,12,0,0,0,0,12V219a12,12,0,0,0,12,12H149a12,12,0,0,0,12-12V12A12,12,0,0,0,149,0Z"/>
<path d="M134.46,179.67h-2.81a1.08,1.08,0,0,1-.76-1.84l2-2a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,0-2.18l-2.53-2.53a1.58,1.58,0,0,0-2.18,0l-2,2a1,1,0,0,1-.75.32,1.12,1.12,0,0,1-.76-.3,1,1,0,0,1-.33-.78v-2.81a1.55,1.55,0,0,0-1.54-1.54h-3.58a1.55,1.55,0,0,0-1.54,1.54v2.81a1.07,1.07,0,0,1-1.09,1.08,1,1,0,0,1-.75-.32l-2-2a1.58,1.58,0,0,0-2.18,0l-2.53,2.53a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,0,2.18l2,2a1.08,1.08,0,0,1-.76,1.84h-2.81a1.55,1.55,0,0,0-1.54,1.54v3.58a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,1.54,1.55h2.81a1.08,1.08,0,0,1,.76,1.84l-2,2a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,0,2.18l2.53,2.53a1.58,1.58,0,0,0,2.19,0l2-2a1,1,0,0,1,.75-.32,1.07,1.07,0,0,1,1.09,1.08v2.81a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,1.54,1.55h3.58a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,1.54-1.54v-2.81a1.07,1.07,0,0,1,1.09-1.08,1,1,0,0,1,.75.32l2,2a1.58,1.58,0,0,0,2.18,0l2.53-2.53a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,0-2.18l-2-2a1.08,1.08,0,0,1,.76-1.84h2.81a1.55,1.55,0,0,0,1.54-1.54v-3.58A1.55,1.55,0,0,0,134.46,179.67ZM124.89,183a3.89,3.89,0,1,1-3.89-3.89A3.89,3.89,0,0,1,124.89,183Z"/>
<path d="M106.92,175.17h-2a.75.75,0,0,1-.53-1.29l1.39-1.39a1.08,1.08,0,0,0,0-1.53L104,169.19a1.11,1.11,0,0,0-1.53,0l-1.39,1.39a.73.73,0,0,1-.53.22.78.78,0,0,1-.53-.21.73.73,0,0,1-.23-.55v-2A1.08,1.08,0,0,0,98.75,167h-2.5a1.08,1.08,0,0,0-1.08,1.08v2a.75.75,0,0,1-.76.76.73.73,0,0,1-.53-.22l-1.39-1.39a1.11,1.11,0,0,0-1.53,0L89.19,171a1.08,1.08,0,0,0,0,1.53l1.39,1.39a.75.75,0,0,1-.53,1.29h-2A1.08,1.08,0,0,0,87,176.25v2.5a1.08,1.08,0,0,0,1.08,1.08h2a.75.75,0,0,1,.53,1.29l-1.39,1.39a1.08,1.08,0,0,0,0,1.53L91,185.81a1.11,1.11,0,0,0,1.53,0l1.39-1.39a.73.73,0,0,1,.53-.22.75.75,0,0,1,.76.76v2A1.08,1.08,0,0,0,96.25,188h2.5a1.08,1.08,0,0,0,1.08-1.08v-2a.75.75,0,0,1,.76-.76.73.73,0,0,1,.53.22l1.39,1.39a1.11,1.11,0,0,0,1.53,0l1.77-1.77a1.08,1.08,0,0,0,0-1.53l-1.39-1.39a.75.75,0,0,1,.53-1.29h2a1.08,1.08,0,0,0,1.08-1.08v-2.5A1.08,1.08,0,0,0,106.92,175.17Zm-6.7,2.33a2.72,2.72,0,1,1-2.72-2.72A2.73,2.73,0,0,1,100.22,177.5Z">
<animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                    attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="0 97.5 177.5"
                    to="360 97.5 177.5"
                    dur="1s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Ways to achieve this effect with CSS without animateTransform?

Comment: @SurabWeb Use the `transform-origin` property

Comment: Can you take a look and let me know what's wrong with this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBjeer

Comment: For SVGs "50% 50%" is the middle of the SVG, not the middle of the object. Add `transform-box: fill-box;`to your CSS (https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/wxWjNV). Or for better compatibility with other/older browsers, use `px` instead of `%` (https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/PBzeLg).

Answer (score 0):

You can add transform-origin in path css, to make your animation centered.

```
path {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

And make it spin by changed the animateTransform to :

```
<animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                attributeName="transform"
                type="rotate"
                from="0 0 0"
                to="360 0 0"
                dur="1s"
                repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

And move your path of small gear to center of big gear.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good answer because (a) percentage values work differently in SVGs, and (b) they currently aren't implemented in a compatible way in all browsers anyway (Chrome doesn't follow the spec).